# The 'break' command in Loops

Tags: javascript, break

I'm a new  JS Learner and I'd like to understand this :
When I try to remove the "break" command and search for a name like "Chris" always find that the "if" statement is skipped and get the response from The "else" statement!

```js
const contacts = ['Chris:2232322', 'Sarah:3453456', 'Bill:7654322', 'Mary:9998769', 'Dianne:9384975'];
const para     = document.querySelector('p');
const input    = document.querySelector('input');
const btn      = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let searchName = input.value.toLowerCase();
  input.focus();
  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    let splitContact = contacts[i].split(':');
    if (splitContact[0].toLowerCase() === searchName) {
       para.textContent = splitContact[0] + '\'s number is ' + splitContact[1] + '.';
       break;
    } else {
       para.textContent = 'Contact not found.';
    }
  }
});
```

P.S/ sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What is your question?

Comment: why that happen, i mean "chris" is the first item in the Array !!

Comment: I recommend you use a step-through debugger to find out: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: ok from what i understood :
i get the answer from "if" statement then the value change to the one in "else" statement right!
But why that happen, i mean as long as the condition is true shouldn't it just skip the "else" statement ?

Comment: Your `if` and `else` branches are **inside** the `for` loop, so the `else` branch is taken **for every entry in `contacts`** that doesn't match. I strongly recommend you use a Step-Through Debugger so you can see what your program is doing.

Comment: use your browser's  Debugger  (**F12**)

Comment: ok i get now, thank you for explaining this

Comment: when i removed the "break" statement chrome Debugger (console) didn't show anything, that's why i asked here trying to understand, anyway sorry if it was dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is not skipped, if you add a console.log() inside the if, it will log to the console if there is a match. It will however show 'Contact not found' in your paragraph because the loop will still run and the last run will not be a match. Try looking for 'Dianne', you will have a match.

Using a break in will make your code work but is not the most elegant way to do it. You could use a find function like this:

```js
const contacts = ['Chris:2232322', 'Sarah:3453456', 'Bill:7654322', 'Mary:9998769', 'Dianne:9384975'];
const para = document.querySelector('p');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let searchName = input.value.toLowerCase();
  input.focus();
  
  const searchResult = contacts.find(contact => (
    contact.split(':')[0].toLowerCase() === searchName
  ));
  
  if (searchResult) {
    const contact = searchResult.split(':');
    para.textContent = contact[0] + '\'s number is ' + contact[1] + '.';
 } else {
   para.textContent = 'Contact not found.';
 }
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Search</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: you are right i got a match with "Dianne", so i guess that happened because it was the last one in the loop right ?